# Highcharts X-axis EndTick always should end in current date

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

[image]

This is a **line chart** of **DateTime type** and when I decrease the size of the browser the tick on the x-axis changes.

What I would like is **to keep the end date fixed** with the **current date**, even if the size of the browser page changes.

Can anyone let me know how will that work?

Comment: Try [`xAxis.endOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.endOnTick)

Answer (score 1):

`tickPositioner` callback function gives you an access to tick generated by Highcharts. This code removes the last tick and inserts a custom one:

```
tickPositioner: function() {
  this.tickPositions.pop();
  this.tickPositions.push(Date.UTC(1971, 5, 23));
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/h6ttu3v8/

This causes that the last tick will always fall on 23 June. Also make sure that extremes on your axis have proper values so that the last tick is visible.

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickPositioner